# Angular 2 - Service as NgModule to not have to declare all providers?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service called CalculationService, which is declared `@Injectable()`. This service uses a whole lot of other injected classes, each of which is also declared as `@Injectable()` and given to the constructor of CalculationService via `@Inject()`.

Now when I want to use the service inside my app, the AppComponent looks like this (for the sake of convenience, I omitted the Typescript imports):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routeConfig),
    PlannerModule
  ],
  providers: [
    InputService,
    Bausparen,
    BausparenInput,
    Girokonto,
    GirokontoInput,
    Immobilien,
    ImmobilienInput,
    Lebensversicherung,
    LebensversicherungInput,
    Rentenversicherung,
    RentenversicherungInput,
    Tagesgeld,
    TagesgeldInput,
    Termingeld,
    TermingeldInput,
    Wertpapiere,
    WertpapiereInput
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I don't need to access all the providers declared in the app module directly. The only class in need is the CalculationService but I don't know how to declare the providers in the Service.

Is there a way to refactor the service as a module, i.e. declare the providers inside the CalculationService? Or do I have to get rid of all the `@Injectable()`s (Bausparen and so on) and create objects inside the Calculation Service, so that no provider is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't register providers on or in services. You can only register them in modules or at components.

What you can do is to create a module for your service, then you only need to add the module to `imports: [...]` and all providers are registered globally.

If it is a lazy loaded module you need to implement and import `forRoot()`

Comment: When I declare my service as NgModule, then what to put in `declarations` and `bootstrap`?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried modules without `declarations` myself, but I would try to just omit `declarations` and `bootstrap`.